# Entity Framework Attaching an object but not calling SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Below is an example code which should demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    public static void addRecord(CargoShip ship, DbContext db)
    {
        // Realistically, in my application this is decided by business logic, - omitted for brevity
        long containerTypeIDNewContainer = 5;

        Container containerToAdd = new Container()
        {
            cargoShipBelongingToID = ship.cargoShipID,
            containerTypeID = containerTypeIDNewContainer
        };
        ship.Containers.Add(containerToAdd);

        // This line of code is what I want to be able to do
        // WITHOUT doing a db.SaveChanges

        // ContainerType is a lookup table in the database, each container type has pre-defined
        // Height/Width etc

        // This throws a null exception, ContainerType object does not exist.
        string containerHeight = containerToAdd.ContainerType.Height;
    }
```

I basically want to be able to create a new `Container` and fill in a foreign key on that object, and be able to access the child of the foreign key as an object in code.

if I call a SaveChanges, it will naturally go and fetch the values for the Container object, but I want to fill in those values/objects without having to do a Savechanges.

**edit:**

Forgot to mention incase it is not clear. The relationship is: `CargoShip` has many `Container`, a `Container` has ONE `ContainerType`, which is a FK and is non nullable.

Can you help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF will *not* fill in all your FK properties for you just because you set an ID in your entity. Those properties will only be set after you call `SaveChanges`.

For that reason, there's not much point in calling `Add` unless you do actually intend to call `SaveChanges` at some point.

If you simply want to get the appropriate `ContainerType`, then you may as well do a `Select` (or `Find`) - which ultimately boils down to much the same SQL query that EF would have to use behind the scenes anyway:

```
var containerType = db.ContainerTypes.Find(containerTypeIdNewContainer);
```

Note that the `Find` method will only go to the DB if the particular `containerType` record does not already exist in the local cache. However, the lifetime of the local cache is tied to the lifetime of the `DbContext`, so may be very short.

It may make sense to maintain your own cache of commonly-used entities like this if they're relatively stable:

```
var containerTypes = db.ContainerTypes.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);

...

var containerType = containerTypes[containerTypeIdNewContainer];
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wanted my cake and wanted to eat it too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can access your DbContext (not familiar with EntityFrameworkConnection class) then you can simply use an IQueryable.

```
IQueryable<T> query = db.Set<ContainerType>()

var containerType =  query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.containerTypeID == containerTypeIDNewContainer)

string containerHeight = containerType.Height;
```

Hope I understood your question properly

Comment: For some reason I cannot seem to add the word "ContainerType" inside the query = db.Set<ContainerType>().

Comment: You may have misunderstood slightly, this is what I'm trying to avoid, I don't want to have to go fetch the ContainerType object from the database. I wanted a 'better' way of doign this, e.g. attaching the object or something.